# AOP w/ PostSharp - Classic NotifyPropertyChanged PropertyChanged Event Handler Missing?

Tags: c#, .net, aop, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

New to PostSharp 2.0 and trying out the class NotifyPropertyChanged AOP provided here:
http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/ui#undo-redo

When I attempt to hook into the PropertyChanged event handler the compiler tells me it is not defined.  I have not directly implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on the object in question, only applied the attribute.

I would assume the answer is to implement the interface but this defeats the simplicity a bit, am I missing something or is that also a requirement?

Is there any way to get PostSharp to modify the class pre-compile to introduce these members/interfaces?

Comment: For specific cases, you can implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and declare the event on the class you need to work with. Your aspect will still work. If you need it at compile time then you have to explicitly declare it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose, you are trying to subscribe to the event in the same assembly. PostSharp is rewriting your assembly after it has been compiled. So this will only work, if you reference the assembly that has been rewritten by the PostSharp binary rewriter.

Comment: Is there any way to get PostSharp to modify it somewhere before the primary compile step starts?  What is the workaround then, to just implement the interface and event as well as the [MarkupAttribute]?

Comment: To modify it before compilation would mean to modify your code. PostSharp is not going to do that. Your work around sounds reasonable, but I don't know whether it will work or not. I suggest, you simply try it.